# How to send user registration to PHP and MySQL from Android?

Tags: android

My code

```
public class Signup extends Fragment {

String[] gender1 = {"Select gender", "Male", "Female"};
int[] image = {R.mipmap.ic_gender_male_female, R.mipmap.ic_gender_male_female, R.mipmap.ic_gender_male_female};
Button singup;
Spinner spinner;
TextView alreadymember;
String selected_gender;
EditText name, email, uname, password, cpassword, dob;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
    alreadymember = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    singup = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    name = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    email = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    uname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    password = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    cpassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    dob = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), gender1, image);
    spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), gender1[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

call async

```
          singup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String s[] = new String[6];
            s[0] = name.getText().toString().trim();
            s[1] = email.getText().toString().trim();
            s[2] = uname.getText().toString().trim();
            //s[3]=dpassword;
            s[3] = cpassword.getText().toString().trim();
            s[4] = "" + spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            s[5] = dob.getText().toString().trim();
            String cgender = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            String dpassword = password.getText().toString().trim();
             SingupAsyn singupAsyn = new SingupAsyn();
            singupAsyn.execute(s);
      }
       });  return v;}
```

Asynctask here

```
    private class SingupAsyn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage(" Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        /*
            Receive data which is input by user
         */

        String cname = params[0];
        String cemail = params[1];
        String cuname = params[2];
        String dcpassword = params[3];
        String cdob = params[4];
        String cgender = params[5];
        try {
            url = new URL("here url");             
           connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("user_full_name", cname);
            jsonObject.accumulate("user_email", cemail);
            jsonObject.accumulate("user_name", cuname);
            jsonObject.accumulate("user_password", dcpassword);
            jsonObject.accumulate("user_dob", cdob);
            jsonObject.accumulate("user_gender", cgender);
            outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            outputStreamWriter.write(jsonObject.toString());
            outputStreamWriter.flush();
            outputStreamWriter.close();
            Log.d("YOUR DATA", "" + jsonObject);
            Log.v( "postURL: " ,""+url);
       int res = connection.getResponseCode();
             return ("" + res);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Get response

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Log.d("ok", s);
            int s1 = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if ((s1== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED) || (s1 ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)) {          
    pDialog.dismiss();             
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Registration Success" + s,          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
           else {      pDialog.dismiss();
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "failure" + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like a server end problem.

Comment: Means my code is correct

Comment: You are gettin `200` response code. It  means you sending and receiving request and response correctly. But server is some how not able to save the data.

Comment: yes, should be a server side issue, since you got an okay response. try sending the parameter via other means. you can use tools like `postman` or  `curl`